# Need to freeze column in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a table in sharepoint with 40 columns. I need a javascript code for freezing first column. 
i.e., when horizontal scroll-bar is moved, first column remain freezed.

Answer (score 2):

What does "...table in sharepoint..." mean?

- An SPList (a custom list)?
- An HTML table on a master page/page/web part?
- A server-side control such as a ListView?

This sounds more like a CSS question even though JavaScript will likely be the mechanism that applies the necessary styles.  If you have a table with 40 columns you may want to rethink your UI anyway.  If this isn't possible, perhaps you could have two tables, one to hold the first column and the other to hold the remaining 39 (which could be placed in a div and made to scroll horizontally).